# More Kafka consumers than partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've saw a lot of questions about of this subject but I'm not very convinced. Is there a way to have more different consumers with a different `group.id` value than partitions number ?
Is a good workaround to achive this in the java code ?

Answer (score 0):

Consumer Groups in Kafka is one way of parallelism in consuming the data. Multiple consumers can join a consumer group so that every individual consumer can consume data from different partitions of the Kafka Topic.

In addition to the above Kafka can track the Active consumers of a particular Group by using the `group.id`.

Therefore, having more consumers than partitions is ineffective as each partition is consumed by only one consumer in a consumer group to maintain the total order of messages consumed. **Kafka only provides total ordering on all the partitions rather than maintaining order per partition.**

But, you can still have multiple consumer groups consuming same topic which is more of a Publish/Subscribe rather than Point-to-Point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different group id, then the partitions are not assigned to the same consumer group.

Basically, If you have N partitions and M distinct group ids, you can have at most N * M consumer threads polling from that topic. Any more, and you've oversubscribed for a particular group.